# Viewing the String Value of a Toast and changing it

Tags: android

```
<string name="next_toast">Correct</string>
```

I want the value to change to a variable

for example

```
next_toast = getNextQuestion();
```

How do I accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource is constant, by definition they can't it updated. However, `Toast.makeText()` has two versions, one that takes a string resource id and another one that takes a plain `CharSequence` (String).

[Toast Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29)